# How do I define syntax and translations for this datatype?

Tags: syntax, isabelle

So currently I have the following datatype:

```
datatype ('a) action = Action (name: string) "int option" "int option" "'a option" "bool option" "string option"
```

I want to define syntax such that the term `example(3, 4, True)` will be translated to `Action ''example'' (Some 3) (Some 4) None (Some True) None`.

What I've done so far is the following:

```
syntax
  "_example" :: "[int, int, bool] ⇒ 'a action" ("3example'((_), (_), (_)')" [60, 60, 60] 60)
translations
  "_example a b c"  ⇌ "CONST Action ''example'' (Some a) (Some b) None (Some True) None"
```

Unfortunately, Isabelle complains that the right hand side contains too many variables.

```
Error in syntax translation rule: rhs contains extra variables
("_example" a b c) ↝
  ("\<^const>Scratch.action.Action" ("_String" ''example'')
    (Some a) (Some b) None (Some True) None)
```

I've seen other syntax that uses variables in the left hand side and their translations work. May I know why doesn't mine work and how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your example that explain the error message you get:

1. Given an AST rewrite rule (*lhs*, *rhs*), it must hold that all variables in *rhs* must also occur in *lhs*. Since you are defining two AST rewrite rules simultaneously via `⇌`, namely a parse rule (`⇀`) and a print rule (`↽`), it turns out that variable `c` does not occur in the *lhs* of the print rule. I would guess that the intended purpose of `c` was to use it in the *rhs* instead of `True`.
2. While processing the *rhs*, Isabelle assumes `Some` and `None` to be *variables* instead of constants, so you need to use the `CONST` prefix to enforce treatment as constants (e.g., `CONST None` and `CONST Some a`).
3. String literals such as `''example''` are also treated as variables. In this case, adding `CONST` would not do, so you could use `[CHR 0x65, CHR 0x78, CHR 0x61, CHR 0x6d, CHR 0x70, CHR 0x6c, CHR 0x65]` instead, which is cumbersome. I'm not aware of any alternative.
4. You need to add outermost parentheses when using block indentation in your mixfix annotation, i.e., you need to write `"(3example'((_), (_), (_)'))"` instead of `"3example'((_), (_), (_)')"`.

So, for your particular example my suggestion is to use an abbreviation as follows:

```
abbreviation example :: "[int, int, bool] ⇒ 'a action" ("(3example'((_), (_), (_)'))" [60, 60, 60] 60) where
  "example(a, b, c) ≡ Action ''example'' (Some a) (Some b) None (Some c) None"
```

For further information on syntax transformations and mixfix annotations please refer to Sections 8.5 and 8.2 respectively in [The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/isar-ref.pdf)